# How to display user-submitted data on same page

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabular

In this HTML, the user is asked to input personal data. To gather them, I know I'm supposed to use an array and gather them all there. In the div inline, I plan to display the user's inputs in a table. But how do you actually do it?

```js
tab=[];

function submitdata(){
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf-8" />

<title>Form</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://birdis.notacat.com/css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://birdis.notacat.com/css/awwwards.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://birdis.notacat.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://birdis.notacat.com/js/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://birdis.notacat.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.5"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".various").fancybox({
  maxWidth : 392,
  maxHeight : 580,
  fitToView : true,
  padding     : 0,
  margin      : 0,
  width  : '70%',
  height  : '70%',
  autoSize : true,
  closeClick : false,
  openEffect : 'elastic',
  closeEffect : 'elastic'
 });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
   
   <h1><img src="Fourth Quarter Project/images/welcome.png" alt="welcome" /></h1>
   
 <form name="PersonalInfo">
 <p>
 <br><br>
 First Name: <input type="text" name="firstNameTextField" placeholder="Your First Name">
 <br><br>
 Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastNameTextField" placeholder="Your Last Name">
 <br>
 
 <br>
 Grade Level:
 <br><br>
 <input type="radio" value="A" name="gradeLevel"> Grade 7 <br>
 <input type="radio" value="B" name="gradeLevel"> Grade 8 <br>
 <input type="radio" value="C" name="gradeLevel"> Grade 9 <br>
 <input type="radio" value="D" name="gradeLevel"> 4th Year <br>
 
 <br>
 <br>
 Section: <select name="section">
     <option> Emerald </option>
     <option> Diamond </option>
     <option> Ruby </option>
     <option> Camia </option>
     <option> Jasmin </option>
     <option> Sampaguita </option>
     <option> Potassium </option>
     <option> Rubidium </option>
     <option> Sodium </option>
     <option> Electron </option>
     <option> Neutron </option>
     <option> Proton </option>
    </select>
 
 <br><br>
  Date of Birth: <input type="text" name="month" placeholder="mm" size=1 maxlength="2"> / 
      <input type="text" name="day" placeholder="dd" size=1 maxlength="2"> /
      <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="yyyy" size=1 maxlength="4">
      
  <br><br>
  
  Contact Number: <input type="text" name="contactNumberTextField" placeholder="Your Contact Number">
  
  <br><br>
  
  Address:
  <br><textarea name="address" rows=3 cols=30> </textarea>
 </p>
 <br>
 </form>
   
    <div id="blackbox">
    <input type="submit"> Submit </input>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="blackbox">
    <a class="various" href="#inline">Display</a>
    </div>
    
    <button onClick=submitData()> Submit </button>
    <button onClick=displayData(submitData())> Display </button>
    
    
  </div>
  

  
 </div>
 

 <div id="inline" style="width: 386px; display: none;">
  <span class="inspiration">Your Personal Information</span>
  <p>Angela Mae</p>
  <div class="right">- <span class="red"></span></div>
  <div class="visitbox">
  <h2><a href="" ></a></h2>
  <span class="count"><span class="tenpix"></span></span>
  </div>
  <p><br/>
   <span class="cursive"><a href="">#kakuri</a>, <a href="">#wat<a>,</p>
  <p><span class="tenpix"></span></p>
  
  <p><a href="" ></a> <span class="orjust"></span> <span class="send"><a href="" ></a></span></p>

 </div>
 
 <script>
  
  var tab=[];
  
  function submitData(){
   tab.push(document.forms["PersonalInfo"][firstNameTextField]);
   return tab[];
  }
 
  function displayData(t){
   alert t;
  }
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tab=[];

function submitData(){
    document.forms["PersonalInfo"].firstNameTextField.value;
    return tab;
}

function displayData(t){
    console.log(t);
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function displayData(){
    var data = $('form#PersonalInfo').serializeArray();

    $.each(data, function(i,obj){
       console.log(obj.name +" : '" + obj.value + "'");
    });
}
```